# How can I set a default value in a drop-down list, but still be able change the selection with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have a tampermonkey script I hacked together with some JavaScript, JQuery, and google-fu. It runs on a specific webpage where I enter some data.

The drop-down lists on this webpage are huge, but for the majority of them I only use a specific option (or few options). I am running into a problem when I need to change one of the values of the drop-down to something else, but it reverts back to the default option.

```
 $(document).ready(()=>{
            $("#MainContent_Lead").val('64');
            $("#MainContent_Meeting").val('1');
            $("#MainContent_Duration").val('30');
```

Line #2: The value set for lead is the only option I would ever select in that drop-down, it works great.

Line #3: For the next drop-down, I use val 1 about 90% of the time, so I want val 1 to be selected by default, but I also need to be able to change the value on occasion. Currently when I change it, it reverts back immediately.

Line #4: Strangely enough, the third drop-down is also something that I need to change frequently, but when I change the value it works as intended.

What do I need to do to set val 1 for #MainContent_Meeting by default, but allow me to change it when needed?

Comment: There's nothing here that cause the value to change back. Something else is doing that.

Comment: You do the same thing in #3 and #4, how could they possibly behave differently all by themselves?

Comment: Please amend your question and add your html. With SO you can even create a working demo of your code/html

Comment: Maybe it's possible to don't change the value, but the [selected attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp).